# Declaring fines / offence on Australian visa application

Tags: visas, australia

I was fined for urinating in public in the Netherlands and given an on the spot fine. Do I need to declare this on an Australian visa application?[image]

Comment: Did you receive a written notice or citation or receipt during the incident? Did the officer take information from your ID or passport? What is the actual wording of the question in the visa application?

Comment: Yes I got a letter but it was in Dutch. It is classed as an administrative fine. They did take my ID

Comment: a) If you still have the letter, obscure your ID info (name, address, passport number, whatever), then attach the modified copy of the letter to your question, using the "Edit" button and then the "moon and mountains" button just above the text composition box. Then b) what is the actual text of the question in the visa application?

Comment: The question is have you ever been convicted of any offence in any country? Let me see if I can find the letter

Comment: Picture added..

Comment: Picture doesn't show, even after reloading the page. Does it show to you?

Comment: Try now. I can see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137899/discussion-between-m1997-and-davidsupportsmonica).

Answer (score 6):

> have you ever been convicted of any offence in any country?

Your piece of paper quite literally says:

> You are guilty of committing a criminal offence.

Looking at https://www.justid.nl/onderwerpen/strafblad-en-het-justitieel-documentatie-systeem/overtreding-en-uitzonderingen it's quite possible this got on your criminal record because 140 EUR is more than 130 EUR... Ouch.

See https://www.justid.nl/onderwerpen/strafblad-en-het-justitieel-documentatie-systeem/inzien-van-het-strafblad on how to request your criminal record.

I would disclose this if I were you.

Comment: It is unfortunate artefact of different countries having different penalty systems. In a number of European countries, the base rule is that the "criminal" law system includes anything that leads to punishment on a specific individual, including violation of municipal ordinances. Yet in Canada, even an imprisonment of five years (less a day) could be technically non-criminal under provincial laws (which under the Canadian system technically is not "criminal") and does not lead to inadmissibility in Canada (but Australian language is more general here).

Comment: In any case, Australian admissibility are usually not affected by one-time violations that led to less than a year's imprisonment. A declaration would be the best.